# Difference between vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges and vkCmdPipelineBarrier in Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

Consider the following code that copys an `srcImage` from gpu to cpu `dstImage`:

```
vkCmdCopyImage(command_buffer, srcImage,
               VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, dstImage,
               VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &copy_region);
VkImageMemoryBarrier visible_barrier = {
      VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,  // VkStructureType            sType
      nullptr,                                 // const void*                pNext
      VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,            // VkAccessFlags              srcAccessMask
      VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT,                 // VkAccessFlags              dstAccessMask
      VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,    // VkImageLayout              oldLayout
      VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL,                 // VkImageLayout              newLayout
      VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                 // uint32_t                   srcQueueFamilyIndex
      VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                 // uint32_t                   dstQueueFamilyIndex
      dstImage,                                 // VkImage                    image
      {VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1}  // VkImageSubresourceRange    subresourceRange
  };
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
                     0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &visible_barrier);
vkMapMemory()
vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges()//Do we need this line at all?
vkUnmapmemory()
```

The barrier(i.e. memory dependency) above already generates an availability operation that makes the write to `dstImage` available in the device domain, a memory domain operation that makes the write in the device domain available to the host domain, and a visibility operation that makes the write visible to the host.

Is there still a need to call `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges`, after the barrier, to make the write visible to the host?

Answer (score 1):

`vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` is used to make sure your mapped memory is valid, if the device memory is not host coherent.

`vkCmdPipelineBarrier` is used to make sure your GPU won't run commands out of order, it's a synchronization mechanism inside the GPU.

They are two totally different thing.

To your question, whether to use `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` depends on two things:

1. do you want to read the content of the target image back on CPU side? If no, I don't see any reason to call `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges`.
2. if you do want to read the content back, does the device memory your target image bound host coherent? If yes, you don't need `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges`

Comment: Pipeline barriers can also imply a memory barrier for accessibility and visibility, they are not just in-GPU synchronization. But they are not sufficient by themselves for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the invalidate is still needed. In addition to the rules in the memory dependency section, you *also* have to apply the rules in the access flags section.

From section "7.1.3 Access Types" in the Vulkan 1.3 specification:

> If a memory object does not have the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT` property, then [...] `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` **must** be called to guarantee that writes which are available to the host domain are made visible to host operations.